# Extendscript xml with dash element node

Tags: javascript, extendscript

How do you access to an xml element with dash inside it? And modify it?
Exemple:

```
<root>
 <bookstore>
      <Author>
           <book-en>sample</book-en>
           <book-fr>test</book-fr>
           <book-de>testtest</book-de>``
           etc.....
```

I try with:

- myxml.bookstore.Author.book-en="toto"-->Not work
- myxml.bookstore.Author.('book-en')="toto"-->Not work
- myxml.bookstore.Author.child(1)="toto"-->Not work

Please, can you help me??? Thx a lot!! ;-)

Syme

Comment: getElementsByTagName("book-en")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_get.asp

Comment: Don't work with Extendscript. In javascript ok, but not in Adobe extendscript toolbox....

Comment: ohh sorry then i couldn't help you

Comment: myxml.bookstore.Author["book-en"] = "toto"; works for me (estk4)

Comment: Oh my god!!!! It works!!!!!! I do that but with the point... Thx a lot miiligramme!!! :-D